# Help convert .asp to .php

Tags: php, asp-classic

How can I rewrite this from .asp to .php?

```
<%
' Url of the webpage we want to retrieve
thisURL = "pagerequest.jsp" 

' Creation of the xmlHTTP object
Set GetConnection = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

' Connection to the URL
GetConnection.Open "get", thisURL, False
GetConnection.Send 

' ResponsePage now have the response of the remote web server
ResponsePage = GetConnection.responseText

' We write out now the content of the ResponsePage var
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.write (ResponsePage)

Set GetConnection = Nothing
```

%>

Answer (score 6):

How? What you need to do is learn PHP and then write it.

If you already know PHP, then I suspect you'll want to investigate:

1. Whether or not you have remote file_get_contents support. (See the other answers.)
2. Failing that, whether or not you can use the [CURL](http://www.php.net/curl) functions, although you should first check that your production environment has curl support. (If it doesn't, you'll need to rectify this.)
3. Failing all of those, you'll need to create a [socket connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) and send the relevant HTTP headers to request the remote content.

Of the above, I'd almost recommend CURL above file_get_contents, as it can transparently handle re-directs (if you tell it to) and will expose more of the under-pinnings, which may prove useful in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the translated code is (no error checking, just dirt simple functionality):

```
$url = 'http://server/pagerequest.jsp';
$text = file_get_contents($url);
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $text;
```

Note that the `$url` needs to be fully qualified...

**EDIT**: for a more robust solution:

```
function getUrl($url) {
    if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
        return file_get_contents($url);
    } elseif (function_exists('curl_init')) {
        $c = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        return curl_exec($c);
    } else {
        $parts = parse_url($url);
        if (!isset($parts['host'])) {
            throw new Exception('You need a host!');
        }
        $port = isset($parts['port']) ? $parts['port'] : 80;
        $f = fsockopen($parts['host'], $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if (!$f) {
            throw new Exception('Error: ['.$errno.'] '.$errstr);
        }
        $out = "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: {$parts['host']}\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($f, $out);
        $data = '';
        while (!feof($f)) {
            $data .= fgets($f, 128);
        }
        list($headers, $data) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
        // Do some validation on the headers to check for redirect/error
        return $data;
    }
 }
```

Usage:

```
$url = 'http://server/pagerequest.jsp';
$text = getUrl($url);
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $text;
```

Comment: Also note `allow_url_fopen` needs to be enabled for this to work. Otherwise see @middaparka's response.

Comment: @Brad: which is why I upvoted @middaparka's response ;-)...  I'll edit in a CURL option as well...

Comment: @ircmaxwell: I agree, his result is best, however i LOVE saving my fingers from typing thus I'm also a favor of your response. I just thought it was worth mentioning if anyone tries this and it fails (they know what to look for).  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this info guys, I will test out and let you know

Comment: "didn't work" doesn't mean anything.  How didn't it work, what errors were shown, etc...